# MVC Razor - Outputting text in-position to the screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I create a `String` in a view and want to output it to the screen.

Initially I tried `Response.Write` but, due to reasons explained elsewhere on this site, the content appeared at the top of the page.  I then attempted to output the string using `@` like so: `@myString`.

This worked, in that it output the text at the right location but it escaped HTML links that I had put in there. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Until you mark any of the reply as an answer you are going to get same replies more :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `Html.Raw()`:

```
@Html.Raw(MyStringVar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped me to resolve the issue :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of string you will want to use:

```
@{
     var myString = new MvcHtmlString("<tags>Text</tags>");
}
```

Then when you inline render it:

```
@myString
```

It'll display the correct value instead of escaped text.

**Edit: Alternative**

The other option is you can just create the MvcHtmlString inline so it renders appropriately.

```
@(new MvcHtmlString(myString))
```

Comment: or even better `@MvcHtmlString.Create(myString)`

Comment: @Silvermind The `MvcHtmlString.Create` actually does only `new MvcHtmlString`... but agreed the syntax becomes cleaner in Razor views. See https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/MvcHtmlString.cs#L22

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Html.Raw function for this

For example:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.YourString)
```

Answer (score 3):

@model myString

@Html.Raw(Model)

**Try @Html.Raw(myString).**

I do not recommend doing this. You don't send html output to screen for various reasons. if you want to put the text in certain part of the screen, use html/css styling in the view and send only the output.

Comment: There are instances like user controls based off HTML helpers where you want to send HTML straight to the screen.  Generally I would agree with you but a current architecture I'm working out has huge needs for base user controls and direct HTML rendering. So I'm a little less quick to judge someone else for wanting to render inline HTML (Although there are better ways to accomplish this task for this given question, but who knows why they need to do it.)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

```
@Html.Raw(myString)
```